# HTML5 input type=time cannot set or retain seconds on Nexus 7 android tablet

Tags: android, html, input, time

I am trying to use an HTML5 input in a form with type=time, on a Nexus 7 running Android 4.2.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="save" method="POST">
            <input type="time" step=1 value="01:02:03" name="duration"/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This should give me control over a time in the format hh:mm:ss and it does when tested on Chrome on a Windows desktop. However, on the Nexus 7, I am not allowed to retain or set the number of seconds. The input control initally shows "01:02:03", but when I touch on it and change it using the "sliding/rolling number" editor window, then it becomes "01:02" and the seconds are lost. The edit window shows only hours and minutes, with nothing there for the seconds.

I see in http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html that this control is not supported for android - yet it is allowing me to change the hours and minutes. Is there a way to make this control work with seconds on a Nexus 7, without having to resort to a work around using a different method?